# jQuery .prop('checked', false) does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prop

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box" /> Check Me!
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var myFunc = function() {
        if($('#box').prop('checked', false)) {
            $('.form').append('<p>Checkbox is not checked.</p>');
        }
    }

    $('#box').on('change', myFunc);
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3PYm7/

When I use `$('#box').prop('checked', false)` as a condition for the `if` statement it does not work, but `! $('#box').prop('checked')` works just fine!

Comment: Please **read the documentation**: https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2

Comment: wow Felix Kling so helpful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The statement `$('#box').prop('checked', false)` does not return boolean rather set the checked property to false so should not be used in condition and it normal behaviour

```
if($('#box').prop('checked', false))
```

Could be changed to test using `is()` with `:checked` selector.

```
if($('#box').is(':checked'))
```

or

```
if($('#box:checked').length)
```

You can **get the best performance** by using the native javascript

```
if(document.getElementById('box').checked)
```

The working statement `$('#box').prop('checked')` you mentioned returns the checked property value instead of setting.

Comment: `$('#box').prop('checked') === false` would be quicker than jQuery's `:checked`. It'll still get the job done!

Comment: Thanks for pointing for the performance, I have updated the code for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
  if ($('#box').prop('checked')==false) {
      $('.form').append('<p>Checkbox is not checked.</p>');
  }
```

Comment: You can use `if(!$('#box').prop('checked')){}` instead

Answer (score 2):

yeah that's a known one,

`$('#box').prop('checked', false)` is a setter version, it would return the element on which the `.prop()` method has been invoked, not a boolean result. You should use the getter version instead to get the boolean value, `$('#box').prop('checked')`

Read here to know more about [`.prop(property)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1)

Comment: I had the same issue - it is not constructive to get downvoted without a comment. I'll vote you up for a correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if($('#box').is(':checked')) // this will return true or false
```

Answer (score 2):

You have more issues than using a [setter which does not return a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to test a property.

Your code will, when fixed, append the message every time you uncheck.

I suggest this

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5GnF5/)

```
$(function() {
   $('#myform').on("submit", function(e) {
     var checked = $('#box').is(":checked");
     $('#pleaseCheckBoxMessage').toggle(!checked);
     if (!checked) {
       e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
     }
  });
  $("#box").on("click",function() {
    $('#pleaseCheckBoxMessage').toggle(!this.checked);
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem with jQuery, the idea was to have the same function name for getting and setting a value via jQuery, but this is very confusing to newcomers.

For example .val('bla') sets value bla but .val() returns the current value... This is pretty much the same for attr, prop, ... and each of them has a StackOverflow question because someone did not understand how it was supposed to work. Had it been called getProp, setProp, these problems would not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this .It is also another way to checking

```
if (!$('#box').prop('checked')) {
        $('.form').append('<p>Checkbox is not checked.</p>');
    }
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3PYm7/2/)

`$('#box').prop('checked')` It will return true or false when check box is changed